# How to set priority to sockets

Tags: c

I have two udp sockets

1. *:161
2. 1.1.2.2:161

When there is a packet destined for 1.1.2.2:161, I want to make the packet to be received by *.161 and not 1.1.2.2:161. Is there an option I can set to the socket 1.1.2.2:161 while creating which makes it not to receive any packets?

Comment: What is `*.161`? There's no such IP address as `*`.

Comment: showing your `bind` calls / source code might clarify

Answer (score 0):

The question does not make sense.  Only one socket can be bound to a given (address, port) pair at any given time, so the situation presented cannot arise.  There is never any question as to which socket should receive an incoming packet.

Comment: It can be the case, of course, that the same *socket* is bound to multiple (address, port) pairs, but that's an altogether different matter.